# Recovering deleted data from FAT32 using java?

Tags: java, android, fat32, data-recovery

Is it possible to recover deleted data from FAT32 using java ?

Thank you very much.

PS: Are there any free resources???

Comment: Are you aware that such an app requires root permissions (because it needs to access the sdcard raw without filesystem)? Therefore it will only work on rooted devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the following links :

- [Recovering deleted data from FAT32 (a)](http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/Kmadhav/blog/5677-How-to-recover-Windows-XP-system-after-improper-FAT32-to-NTFS-conversion/)
- [Recovering deleted data from FAT32 (b)](http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/jacobluis/blog/1380-Recovering-Lost-Files-from-Windows/)
- [Recovering deleted data in Windows](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/10/24/recover-deleted-files-in-windows/)

Comment: I want to write my own software ;)

Comment: @Paul : Haha ! Please go ahead about it :-)

Answer (score -1):

Java is not the right tool to do this.

Comment: It's probably not the most convenient, but it's no more or less *possible* in Java than any other language capable of manipulating arbitrary binary data.