# Recovery Data Android App using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, data-recovery

I would like to write a simple Android app in order to recover deleted data. First of all I thought about using Photorec (last version) which can be compiled from source code but I don't know how to import this program to my Android Project.

I have seen several tutorials about NDK, but always the native program only have one .c file. In my case I only have the Android.mk and I don't know how to import it.

Could anyone please help me? My app doesn't have to use necessarily Photorec, it was just what I first thought in.

Comment: The NDK doesn't usually have the ability to access anything Java can't, how exactly are you hoping it will be able to undelete things?  From what storage location or volume?

Comment: I would like to recover deleted things from sdcard. Because of that reason I first thought about using Photorec 7.0

Comment: This requires sub-file-system-level access, which I don't believe has been permitted for some time now.  From Android 4.4, you can't even access an entire sdcard at filesystem level, unless the device manufacturer is treating it as the primary external storage (most today treat it as secondary).  Basically, your primary issue is not NDK usage, but that you are probably only going to be able to use the result on hacked device where the security model has been modified.

Comment: I've been looking for other discussion related with my problem and in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106430/recovering-deleted-data-from-fat32-using-java sirDarius says: "you can still write an android app, but with native code, using the NDK". Moreover there are too many application which recover deleted data from sdcard, so there must be a solution.

Comment: Most of the people posting in that question don't know what they are talking about.  However, the initial comment alluding to the permission issue is correct.

Comment: I have root permissions in my phone. That is what you refer to? So there isn't any possible solution to write an app which recover deleted data from sd card?

Comment: If you have root, and **if the specific implementation actually exposes a raw block device** ("emulated" external storage on modern devices probably does not) you can create a native helper application to do the recovery, yes.  As far as building existing C codebases, you may want to look at the option for generating a "Stand along toolchain"

Comment: If this is so complex, why there are too many app like about this?? I think there must be a solution. Moreover, Photorec says that its programm can be run on Android.

Comment: For example "Undelete for Root Users" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete does what I want, so there must be a solution.

Comment: I already addressed the case and possible issues with root in the previous comment.  Stackoverflow is not a code writing or finding service.

Comment: I didn't write this post to get a code writing or finding service. I only asked if there were possible to import a programm having only the Android.mk file